# fedora dnf failure cannont understand how to ABSOLUTE FORCE install of a package

Tags: fedora

my dnf update failed with an error on gdk-pixbuf2-2.38.0-2.fc29.x86_64

then I tryied :

```
 dnf clean packages ; dnf update --allowerasing --skip-broken -y
```

answers

```
Erreur : Erreur du contrôle de transaction :   le fichier 
   /usr/share/thumbnailers/gdk-pixbuf-thumbnailer.thumbnailer
   entre en conflit avec les tentatives d'installation de 
   gdk-pixbuf2-2.38.0-2.fc29.i686 et
   gdk-pixbuf2-2.38.0-2.fc29.x86_64
```

There is no --force nor bruteforce nor absolute install options .... in man pages so.. how to be able to update my system again (I need an update for some other softs & libs)  ?

Comment: Fedora 29 is not flagged as [final](https://fedoraproject.org/wiki/Releases/29/Schedule), yet. You should report this bug: https://fedoraproject.org/wiki/How_to_file_a_bug_report

Comment: Thanks, but I absolutly need a short time solution during response time.

Comment: Just remove the **i686** package. It's better to use a stable/final version of distributions, if you wanna work on it. Testings/betas always have bugs - this is why it's in beta phase.

Comment: this cannot be done it will remove nearly ALL of my system

Comment: Then wait for fixing the packaging bug or switch to fedora 28.

Comment: as said above getting back to F28 is not possible :) (on this machine) but of course I can work from other machines

Comment: Note that removing i686 packages _should_ leave your system in functional state, even if there are a lot of them installed. Nothing in x86_64 Fedora itself really requires 32-bit support.

Answer (score 1):

You probably *shouldn't* do this, but just for completeness, if you *want* to force install a package, download it (maybe with `dnf download`) and then use `rpm -Uvh --force` to force install it. This will usually cause more problems than it solves, but if you want to hammer this particular screw, that's how to do it.